# How strong was Darth Vader?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

Darth Vader was comprised of many robotic parts. Just how strong was he with those parts if we don't take into account modifying his strength with the force? Is there any evidence that he had super strength? He picked up the emperor over head fairly easily when he was pretty beat up so I have to imagine he was strong but just how strong was he?

Comment: He was pretty strong.

Comment: Please clarify, do you assume he has had his Weetabix for breakfast?

Comment: 12. He was 12 strong.

Comment: Over 9,000!!!!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Pretty Strong**

In *Darth Vader Volume 2: Into the Fire*, Darth Vader is thrown into a deadly test by the Emperor as punishment. He is explicitly forbidden from using the Force by Sidious, and it is repeatedly reiterated that Sidious would know if does.

[image]

This is perhaps the only example in canon where we know for certain that he isn't using the Force. It is worth noting that Sidious also damages some of his armor, which he has to temporarily replace with scraps, though.

[image]

Throughout this ordeal, he is shown performing a number of feats of strength, such as lifting a humanoid with only his one arm, digging himself out of rocks, punching through a "[tough exoskeleton](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lava_flea#cite_note-AEYNTK-1)"-ed lava flea, plunging a weapon into a Roggwart, forcing open a big, stone door, supporting his own body weight with one arm, punching through rock, and punching out a solid metal droid. His new Super Battledroid arm is doing a lot, but his "original" right arm and especially his left upper arm are certainly playing a part.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's also said that his mechanical parts are not special or uniquely powerful.

[image]

Comment: So on a scale of 1 to 10 he was a D?

Answer (score -1):

Darth Vader was pretty strong and could easily lift a person one-handed, as was demonstrated in the original trilogy. In **Star Wars - Episode IV: New Hope** he lifted the commander of the rebels' ship with one hand and choked him to death (not using the Force, but tightening his hand over the neck). In **Star Wars - Episode VI: Return of The Jedi** he lifts the Emperor using his left hand, supported by his severe right hand. He was able to carry the Emperor even though he was wounded and exhausted and throw him behind the rail into the abyss.

So to summarize, he had physical strength above that of a weight-lifter, similar to that of Robocop, but not in the extreme super-hero level.

Comment: How do you know that he wasn't using the Force when he performed these feats?

Comment: @Valorum If he was using the Force he would prefer telekinesis, action from a distance, instead of direct physical contact. His cybernetic limbs empowered him, similar to the way they empowered Robocop (both are cyborgs).

Comment: Can you provide some evidence to back up these bold assertions?

Comment: In the original trilogy and Obi-Wan Kenobi TV series, when he wanted to Force lift or Force choke his opponents he did it from afar, without direct physical contact, making them somewhat "levitate" in the air.

Comment: And while that's true, does it mean that when you see him using his limbs, he's not augmenting their strength with the Force?

Comment: Well, he doesn't have to. Cybernetics provides him with the strength he needs. This is corroborated in the above answer.